# Coding a bifurcation diagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, recursion, math

I was wondering what was wrong with my code as I keep getting a weird but similar result to the actual bifurcation diagram. I am using the iterative equation `xn+1 = xn * r(1-xn)`.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize = 1000)
def bifunc():
    R_val = []
    X_val = []
    R = np.linspace(0.5,4,1000)
    for r in R:
        x = 0.5
        for iterations in range(1001):
            x = x*r*(1-x)
            R_val.append(r)
            X_val.append(x)

    plt.plot(R_val, X_val, ls = '', marker = ',')
    plt.show()

bifunc()
```

Here is the image that keeps coming up:
[image: img]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why use a cache when you only call the function once?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Comment: @JohanC, yeah I just removed it, but even if i have written the if statement, the same result appears. Not sure how to remove the excessive lines at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first few iterations don't follow the pattern, they can be left out via an `if`-test. Best also remove the `lru_cache` as it has no real function here and can interfere with testing.

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bifunc():
    R_val = []
    X_val = []
    R = np.linspace(0.5, 4, 1000)
    for r in R:
        x = 0.5
        for iterations in range(1001):
            x = x*r*(1-x)
            if iterations > 100:
                R_val.append(r)
                X_val.append(x)
    plt.plot(R_val, X_val, ls='', marker=',')
    plt.show()

bifunc()
```

[image: resulting plot]

This results in a plot similar to many found on the web. Usually the plots don't start before `R=1` to avoid displaying the flat part between 0.5 and 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, this little problem kept bugging me, the help is greatly appreciated.